# Unable to connect to ssh using public DSA key

Tags: ssh, authentication

I have a UTM that I have configured to send daily logs to a Ubuntu Server through ssh authenticating with a Public DSA key that has been generated by the UTM. (I know DSA is considered less secure than RSA, unfortunately my UTM only offers DSA). I have added the DSA Public Key to `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys`. I have setup r/w permissions for the owner `user` explicitly. I have uncommented `AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. My UTM host not been able to connect, after checking `var/log/auth.log` I found the following message:

`userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-dss not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes [preauth]`

How do I add `ssh-dss` to `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes`?

Comment: @Jakuje thanks I'll try that when I get home this evening.